# Traversing through all nodes in a nested object iteratively (WITHOUT using recursion)

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion, iteration

The code below tells us if a value is found in a multi-level nested object.

I know that this can be easily achieved using recursion, I want to know how it can be done iteratively?

```
function deepSearch(o, value) {

    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {

        if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            return deepSearch(o[k], 
        }

        if (o[k] === value)
            return true;

    });
}
```

Comment: why do you need a non recursive version? do you have an idea of it?

Comment: you want to remove the recursion? just remove the recursion! (delete this: `if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') { return deepSearch(o[k],... }`. NOTE: if you don't test with `o.hasOwnProperty(k)`, you are searching also in prototype inherited properties, not just in the object itself

Comment: @NinaScholz Due to ES5's unoptimized nature for recursion/to avoid maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: Umh ... Your code doesn't take advantage of any optimization, if the depth of objects are exceeding calling stack size.

Comment: @Teemu Exactly; that's why I was looking into an iterative version (or of course, could use tail call optimization in ES6 or trampoline in ES5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-recursive version can look like this:

```js
function deepSearch(obj, value) {
    let queue = [obj],
        found = false;
        
    while (!found && queue.length) {

        let o = queue.shift();

        found = Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
            if (o[k] === value)
                return true;

            if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object')
                queue.push(o[k]);
        });

    }
    return found;
}


//

tree = {
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: {
            d: 2
        }
    },
    e: {
        f: 3
    }
};


console.log(deepSearch(tree, 3));
console.log(deepSearch(tree, 9));
```

The idea is, instead of process a child object immediately via a recursive call, we place it in a queue and keep looping until either the queue is empty or we find what we're looking for.

Also, your original version doesn't work as intended, you need `.some` there, not `.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: {
        prop21: true,
        prop22: {
            prop221: "prop221"
        },
        prop23: "prop23"
    },
    prop3: "prop3",
    prop4: "prop4",
    prop5: [{ prop511: true }, { prop512: false }, { prop513: true }, { prop514: true }],
    prop6: [4, 5, 6],
    prop7: [
        [
            { prop7111: "prop7111" }
        ]
    ]
};
function TraverseObject(data) {
    var currentContextObject = data;
    var currentContextObjectProperties = Object.keys(data);
    var contextStorage = []; //{contextObject: {}, contextObjectProperties: []}
    while (currentContextObjectProperties.length !== 0 || contextStorage.length !== 0) {
        var currentContextProperty = currentContextObjectProperties.shift();
        if (currentContextProperty) {
            if (!currentContextObject.hasOwnProperty(currentContextProperty)) {
                break;
            }
            var currentContextPropertyValue = currentContextObject[currentContextProperty];
            if (typeof currentContextPropertyValue === "object") {
                contextStorage.push({
                    contextObject: currentContextObject,
                    contextObjectProperties: currentContextObjectProperties
                });
                currentContextObject = currentContextPropertyValue;
                currentContextObjectProperties = Object.keys(currentContextObject);
                continue;
            }
            console.log(`${currentContextProperty}--${currentContextPropertyValue}`);
        }
        if (currentContextObjectProperties.length === 0 && contextStorage.length !== 0) {
            var popStorage = contextStorage.pop();
            currentContextObject = popStorage.contextObject;
            currentContextObjectProperties = popStorage.contextObjectProperties;
        }
    }
}

TraverseObject(data);
```

This will do the job.
Space complexity can be reduced a bit by deleting the properties already been visited.